# Solve Cost Function $J = \sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2} + \lambda\lVert w \rVert^2 $ Using Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, convex-optimization, regression, least-squares

After struggling for a few days I feel a bit more comfortable solving the cost function

$J = \sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2} + \lambda\lVert w \rVert^2 $

for $w$ using vector calculus.  However, when I learned to solve the simpler ordinary least squares cost function

$J = \sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2}$

I learned with both vector calculus and linear algebra, and the linear algebra derivation was MUCH simpler.

So representing $J = \sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2}$

as

$A\hat{x}=b$

and solving for $\hat{x}$ yielded

$\hat{x} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$.

How can I represent the new cost function $J = \sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2} + \lambda\lVert w \rVert^2 $ similar to the original cost function $A\hat{x}=b$ (using only linear algebra)?  I believe I can solve it easily but I'm a bit unsure how to set it up without using calculus.

Edit: I know the solution will be $\hat{x} = (\lambda I + X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ from vector calculus solution.

Edit 2: Working backward from my solution I get the following

$(\lambda I + X^TX)\hat{x} = X^TY$

distributing $\hat{x}$ yields

$\lambda\hat{x} + X^TX\hat{x} = X^TY$

How do I get rid of the $X^T$ on both sides to figure out the starting expression?  $X^T$ is probably not invertible, since it's likely a data matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target function is
$$
J(w) = \|y-Xw \|_2^2 + \lambda\|w\|_2^2,
$$
taking derivative w.r.t. $w$ and equating ti zero you have
$$
J'(w) = 2 X ^ T(y-Xw)+2\lambda w = 0,
$$
or 
$$
 X ^T Xw + \lambda w = X^Ty ,
$$
taking $w$ common factor
$$
(X ^TX+\lambda I)w=X^Ty,
$$
hence, 
$$
\hat{w}=(X^T X + \lambda I ) ^{-1}X ^T y = H(\lambda)y.
$$
Note that now the hat matrix $H(\lambda)$ is not an orthogonal projection anymore, hence you cannot use $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ as a projection matrix on the column space of the data matrix $X$ without taking into account the "penalty" $\lambda$.

Comment: This is what I overlooked when trying to solve it earlier.  Thank you.